# перевод арабских в римские

Tags: массивы, функции

прошу вас объяснить мне одну вещь, я читал про многомерные массивы, но никак не могу додуматься, дана функция по переводу, она рабочая, я проверял:

```
function romanNumerals(number) {
    var numberArray = number.toString().split("").reverse();
    var result = "";
     var numerals = [
        ["","I","II","III","IV","V","VI","VII","VIII","IX"],
        ["","X","XX","XXX","XL","L","LX","LXX","LXXX","XC"],
        ["","C","CC","CCC","CD","D","DC","DCC","DCCC","CM"],
        ["","M","MM","MMM"]];    
    
    for (var i in numberArray){       
        result = numerals[i][parseInt(numberArray[i])] + result;
    }            
    return result;
}
```

объясните пожалуйста, как цикл находит нужное число, и переводит его из римского в обычное, желательно, подробнее, заранее, благодарен!

Comment: numberArray[i] - элемент на позиции i. Остальное элементарно

Comment: индекс(обычная цифра) соответствует римской

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы разобраться в том как работает функция нужно взять лиcток бумаги и начинать пошагово самому проходить по всему алгоритму. Разберём как работает эта функция на примере 1067:

1. Первая строка, т.е. что хранится в `numberArray`

   1. Переводим число в строку: `"1067"`
   2. Создаём массив из цифр данного числа: `['1', '0', '6', '7']`
   3. Переворачиваем массив: `['7', '6', '0', '1']`
2. Объявляем начальное значение для хранилища ответа: `result = ""`
3. Объявляем набор римских знаков: `numerals = [[...], [...], ...]`
4. Начинаем перебирать индексы в массиве `numberArray`. Т.к. в данном случаем у нас массив имеет длину 4, а нумеруются элементы с 0, то `i` будет пробегать значения от 0 до 3 включительно
5. Начинаем поиск и добавляем предыдущий ответ:

   1. Вычисляем `numerals[0] = ["","I","II","III","IV","V","VI","VII","VIII","IX"]`
   2. Вычисляем `numberArray[0] = '7'`
   3. Выделяем из строки целое число: `parseInt('7') = 7`
   4. Из массива `numerals[0]` находим 7-ой элемент: `numerals[0][7] = "VII"`
   5. Прибавляем к найденному элементу результат: `"VII" + "" = "VII"`
   6. Повторяем родительский пункт для `i = 1`

---

5. Начинаем поиск и добавляем предыдущий ответ:

   1. Вычисляем `numerals[1] = ["","X","XX","XXX","XL","L","LX","LXX","LXXX","XC"]`
   2. Вычисляем `numberArray[1] = '6'`
   3. Выделяем из строки целое число: `parseInt('6') = 6`
   4. Из массива `numerals[1]` находим 6-ой элемент: `numerals[1][6] = "LX"`
   5. Прибавляем к найденному элементу результат: `"LX" + "VII" = "LXVII"`
   6. Повторяем родительский пункт для `i = 2`

---

5. Начинаем поиск и добавляем предыдущий ответ:

   1. Вычисляем `numerals[2] = ["","C","CC","CCC","CD","D","DC","DCC","DCCC","CM"]`
   2. Вычисляем `numberArray[2] = '0'`
   3. Выделяем из строки целое число: `parseInt('0') = 0`
   4. Из массива `numerals[2]` находим 0-ой элемент: `numerals[2][0] = ""`
   5. Прибавляем к найденному элементу результат: `"" + "LXVII" = "LXVII"`
   6. Повторяем родительский пункт для `i = 3`

---

5. Начинаем поиск и добавляем предыдущий ответ:

   1. Вычисляем `numerals[3] = ["","M","MM","MMM"]`
   2. Вычисляем `numberArray[3] = '1'`
   3. Выделяем из строки целое число: `parseInt('1') = 1`
   4. Из массива `numerals[3]` находим 1-ый элемент: `numerals[3][1] = "M"`
   5. Прибавляем к найденному элементу результат: `"M" + "LXVII" = "MLXVII"`
   6. Закончили цикл
6. Вернули результат: `return "MLXVII"`

Comment: большое Вам спасибо, теперь понятно!!!

Comment: @ИванВалучев Обращайтесь! Ничего сложного, просто прошёлся построчно :)

Comment: Вы не могли бы дать мне ссылкой справочную информацию, чтобы я мог изучить, желательно чтобы было не слишком усложненно написано, и по переборам этих массивов, хочу для себя разобраться, а то я ищу, и путного ничего не могу найти, заранее - большое спасибо!!!

Comment: @ИванВалучев С радостью поделюсь! Сам лично учился и начинал с сайта https://learn.javascript.ru/, а дальше уже можно и документацию [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript) почитать. Но всю документацию от и до не читал, конечно. Но повседневно туда захожу чтобы освежить память по некоторым вопросам. Будет огромным плюсом для вас, если будете применять всё на практике. Например сделать простой сайт с динамечской таблицей, сделать форму регистрации с валидацией полей, простую игру типа Икс-Нолик. Чтобы потренероваться в алгоритмах есть хороший сайт https://leetcode.com/

Comment: большое спасибо!!! а вы сейчас в какой сфере работаете, долго ли учились?

Comment: @ИванВалучев Обращайтесь! Я - веб разработчик. Ну как учился, до сих пор учусь) А так опыт 3 года)

Comment: тоже хочу стать веб-разработчиком, как долго длился Ваш путь от начала изучения, до первой работы?

Comment: @ИванВалучев Ну мне было относительно легче влиться в программирование ибо 3 года изучал программирование в университете. Ну я на работу устроился практически с нулевым опытом и за 1.5 года вырос до миддла :)